# Is 'averageness' in the study of facial attraction ethnicity specific?

Tags: physical-attraction, attraction

Is 'averageness' in the study of facial attraction ethnicity specific? I just always wondered whether the 'beauty' ideal of "averageness" is human wide, or is the average across some group or groups.

[Wikipedia defines averageness at the start of the article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Averageness) as:

> ... the physical beauty that results from averaging
>   the facial features of people of the same gender and approximately the
>   same age.

**In regards to culture** it is stated that: *"[t]his principle transcends culture"* and *"[w]hile Europeans also rated average Hadza faces as attractive, the Hadza people expressed no preference for average European faces"* and *"[t]hese results suggest that the rules for extracting attractive faces are culture-independent and innate, but the results of applying the rules depend on the environment and cultural experience."*

Shouldn't the definition at the start of the article then read: *"... from averaging the facial features of people of the same gender age **and ethnicity**"*.

I'm just asking because the results would, I'm guessing, be quite different.

Comment: Thank you for the update. I edited it slightly to improve quotes and emphasize your main question. I believe your question is now clear. My guess would be studies have both calculated average faces across and within different cultures, but I can't find an immediate answer on Wikipedia. +1 Good question.

Comment: clearly, unless my sense of attraction is off, yes